# Cannot locate windows files, in ubuntu 14.0 LTS USB LIVE

Tags: 14.04, boot, ssd, windows-10, filemanager

I was fixing XAMPP open source software with administrative privileges on windows 10 but I ended up locking myself out of my administrative account, and I cannot login because it says ''Password incorrect''. I think I messed something up in the reg-edit 'SAM' folder and unchecked some privileges there, and the administrative account disappeared, and windows started to have issues, I logged out, and couldn't login again but thats not the issue, the problem is I cannot locate the windows files on ubuntu, I want to locate my windows files with Ubuntu and copy/paste it to my external HDD.

EDIT: My SSD has only one partition thats a C: drive, and I cannot locate in UBUNTU 14.04 LTS live usb. I am expecting to get a backup of my windows files thats on the C: drive, with Ubuntu but I cannot locate the drive, or the files as there is only one folder in ubuntu thats computer in file manager, and has Ubuntu's files. Is my SSD not mounted? because I cannot located with

```
fdisk -l
```

command either, it doesn't show the drive, it only shows my USB with the command in the terminal thats connected to my computer and has Ubuntu live on it. Also If can provide info on how I can remove the administrative password of my windows 10 OS that would help, but thats not necessary. I just need to get my backup of my windows files, and reset the windows.

I can provide Screen-shots if this isn't clear enough.

Scrnshots

My SSD is 1tb
[image: SSD IS ONE TB BUT YOU CANNOT FIND IT HERE]
[image: THERE IS NO DRIVE]

Comment: please share some relevant screenshots.

Comment: I added the screen shot. I hope that helps. the issue is simple, my ssd doesn't show the drives thats all on ubuntu live.

Comment: can you add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` you could also try looking though the output of `dmesg` for anything related to the disk